# so i try to create my simple register and login using c

Tags: c

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQSov.png)
so i try to create register and login with c and i got this bug, im using 2 function as u can see, in first function u have to insert username and password, while in second function u have to login using its own variable of user name and password, after that the program will detect if variable from second function is different with variable from first function, if variable from second function isn't the same as first one, the program will loopback while stating that password or username is wrong

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrFX5.png)
but when i run the program, it's automaticly said that my password and username are wrong, so what do i need to do?

```
main(){char username[512];
int password;
printf("Pendaftaran\nMasukan Username = ");
scanf("%s", &username);
printf("Masukan password = ");
scanf("%s", &password);
printf("Registrasi selesai...\n");
login(username, password);}
void login(char username[], int password{
char un[512];
int pw;
printf("Selamat datang di RS XYZ\nSilahkan masukan username = ");
scanf("%s", &un);
if(un[512]=username){
    printf("Masukan password = ");
    scanf("%s", &pw);
    if(pw!=password){
        printf("Password salah\n");
        login(username, password);
    }
    else{
        menu();
    }
}
else{
    printf("Username tidak terdaftar\n");
    login(username, password);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons your question might be down-voted. Finally, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Please post your code direct in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you use username and password of type char, you can't read them by %s (for strings) in the scanf function, use %c (for chars) instead.

If your username and password contain more than 1 char, use a char array. For example char username [20]. Now you can fill them in the scanf function with the parameter %s. To compare them use the function strcmp() (Keep in mind that you have to include string.h)

**A possible solution in your case could be:**

```
main(){
char username[20];
int password;
printf("Enter your username: ");
scanf("%s", &username);
printf("Enter your password: ");
scanf("%d", &password); //as you read int you have to use %d
login(username, password);
}
void login(char username[20], int password
{
char un[20];
int pw;
printf("Enter your username: ");
scanf("%s", &un);
if((strcmp(un,username)==0)){
    printf("Enter pass: ");
    scanf("%d", &pw);
    if(pw!=password){
        printf("Password wrong\n");
        login(username, password);
    }
    else{
        menu();
    }
}
else{
    printf("Username wrong\n");
    login(username, password);
}
```

Comment: i forgot about that, i fix it with using array as u said but it still didn't work

Comment: If you use only char (fe. char username) you have to use %c in scanf instead of %s  / /that should work. If you have char arrays, you can not compare them like above. You have to use strcmp() function.

Comment: i did using array now, i also try using strcmp but its still have a bug like that

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: edited my answer @Jabberwocky

Comment: i change my password variable to int because it's easier to compare it like that

Comment: @MisaelIndraWijaya I posted a possible solution in my answer

Comment: wow thankyou, i really need help for this, this is my final exam in college, i also didnt remember all of string command, thankyou much appreciate

Comment: @MisaelIndraWijaya you are welcome, If you are happy with the answer you can select the answer as helpful